# How to end a user-defined environment having conditional start definitions?

Tags: environments, conditionals

For silly example, the following user-defined environment initiates either the `itemize` environment or the `enumerate` environment, depending on the optional argument. But if the argument variable cannot be referenced in the environment's closing definition, how does one specify whether it is  `itemize` or `enumerate` that is to be ended?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{selectlist}[1]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{itemize}}
      {\begin{itemize}}
      {\begin{enumerate}}
}
      {\end{???????????}}  %This is the question

\begin{document}

\begin{selectlist}{itemize}  
   \item Hello world!   %itemized
\end{selectlist}

\begin{selectlist}{enumerate}
   \item Hello world!   %enumerated
\end{selectlist}   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of opening the environment, use the true/false arguments to define a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{selectlist}[1]
 {%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{itemize}}
    {\def\selectedlist{itemize}}
    {\def\selectedlist{enumerate}}%
  \begin{\selectedlist}%
 }
 {\end{\selectedlist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{selectlist}{itemize}
   \item Hello world!   %itemized
\end{selectlist}

\begin{selectlist}{enumerate}
   \item Hello world!   %enumerated
\end{selectlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, `\ifthenelse` is redundant:

```
\newenvironment{selectlist}[1]
  {\def\selectedlist{#1}\begin{\selectedlist}}
  {\end{\selectedlist}}
```

would do the same. With `xparse` it's even easier:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{selectlist}{m}
 {\begin{#1}}
 {\end{#1}}
```

because in `\NewDocumentEnvironment` the parameters are also available in the “end part”.

Comment: Funny how a solution seems obvious once it's shown to you!  Your point on the redundancy of `\ifthenelse` is also well noted.  May I ask what the purpose of  `{m}` is in your `xparse` solution?

Comment: See the xparse documentation — "m" means one mandatory (curly braces) argument.